# bash script to capture load average every 60 seconds for 2 hours

Tags: bash, unix, load, capture

I want to make a script to run the command below every 60 seconds for 2 hours.
Also want to save the output to a new line each time it is run into a file.

```
uptime | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d "," -f 1
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Use `at` or `crontab` then add `> /path/to/log.file` to the end of your code.

Comment: Unfortunately `awk '{print $12}'` doesn't work correctly if the server has been online less than a day, as the format is different. `15:51:58 up 8 days, 7:33, 1 user, load average: 9.50, 8.32, 8.50` vs `15:51:58 up 23:45, 1 user, load average: 0.01, 0.15, 1.45` After 1 day it has "x days" in the uptime command. Just wanted to comment here as this is a top result in google and don't want others to make the same mistake.

Comment: You can use `cat /proc/loadavg` rather than awking uptime for a more reliable result.

Answer (score 5):

A simple for loop should work for you.

```
for i in {1..120}
do
  uptime | awk '{print $12}' | cut -d "," -f 1 >> /tmp/outputfile
  echo "number of times through: ${i}"
  sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answered script does not work on machines that have a different local language. The output of `uptime` is dependent of the used comma separator of the installed language. You could switch the language with `export LC_ALL=C` and after work switch back to the locale language with `unset LC_ALL`. E.g. *uptime* in a German language environment returns
`15:02:34 up 21 days, 3:52,  1 user,  load average: 0,06, 0,20, 0,33` using a `,` instead of `.` separating the floating point.
`/proc/loadavg` always use the English format and you don't have to worry about the shorter output of *uptime* when the runtime is less than a day:

```
for i in {1..120}
do
  cut -d" " -f1-3 /proc/loadavg >> /path/to/logfile
  sleep 60
done
```